# Set up Virtual Host, can no longer access http://localhost

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I've set up a virtualhost on WAMP.  The address is `http://privatesite` (which works)

However, now that I have set up this virtual host, the default localhost does not work and I'm not sure how to rectify it.

My hosts file looks like this:

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost

127.0.0.1     localhost
127.0.0.1     privatesite
```

My Apache `httpd-vhosts.conf` file looks like this:

```
#
# Virtual Hosts
#
# If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
# machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.

#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
#NameVirtualHost *:80

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/privatesite/trunk/"
    ServerName privatesite
    ServerAlias privatesite
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

As you can see, I have tried to "resetup" the localhost, however, it all seems to point to my "privatesite" folder now it seems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VirtualHost *:80 is like a catch all. You will need to either name your "privatesite" something else or add NameVirtualHost entries for localhost or 127.0.0.1.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html