# The requested url was not found at this server

Tags: ip, wamp, virtualhost, lan

Im trying to access my wamp server over my LAN.

The server is on my desktop and the IP of my desktop is 192.168.2.6

on my laptop i've edited the host file to

```
#127.0.0.1 localhost
192.168.2.6 localhost
```

When I query localhost, I get directed as normal and i'm shown to my desktop wamp index and i can access all sites through this.

However when I query 192.168.2.6  I get:

## the requested URL / was not found on this server.

This normally wouldnt be a problem as i can just query 'localhost' but on my android device I cant edit the hosts file without the device been rooted so need to find away of accessing via IP

Can anyone shed some light on what could be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: 1) It is very strange to edit your hosts file to redirect localhost to another machine
2) Can you access your page on the host desktop using the IP 192.168.2.6 instead of localhost?
3) Can you show us the `Listen` line from your httpd.conf file and any relevant virtual host configurations you have?

Comment: 1) Silly me, i've just realised if i wanted to use something other than 'localhost' it would have to be added to vhosts on the desktop so ive changed that to 'desktophost' and set laptop localhost back to 127... #2) No, I cant access 192.168.2.6 (desktop ip) on desktop or from laptop/mobile, however localhost works on desktop & virtual hosts mapped from my laptop work, just the IP its self doesnt work.....#3) Listen 80 is default, tried also adding Listen 192.168.2.6:80 Vhosts info here : http://pastebin.com/0Vy7vbzp

Comment: I just deleted the 2 default virtual hosts that came installed default with wamp and reordered the virtualhosts in order of file path. Seems to be working now! No idea why it wasnt in the first place but its working now. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Yes, order is important. You want your localhost vhost first if you intend on accessing the root. It looks like yours want being directed to your first vhost which was a non-existant "dummysite" which then couldn't be found. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14075754/set-up-virtual-host-can-no-longer-access-http-localhost Glad you got it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your firewall? Try to disable it and try again. If it works, you've find the problem.

Best regards

Comment: I think the firewall is not the problem since OP is accessing the site on the desktop host from a laptop with `localhost` redirected.